# How do you select each GROUP BY item as a separate column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I get something like:

```
MachID  DownCode    DownTime
PR01    COMP                    30.83
PR02    DIE SET                 378.205277777778
PR02    Die Wait                88.0533333333333
PR03    ColorChg                8.54194444444444
PR04    DieStart                0.205277777777778
```

From the query:

```
SELECT MachID, DownCode, SUM(EndTime - StartTime)/3600 AS DownTime 
FROM vReportDownLog
GROUP BY MachID, DownCode
```

But I really want something like:

```
MachID ColorChg COMP DIE SET DieStart Die Wait
PR01   0        30.83
PR02   0        0    378.205 0        88.0533
PR03   8.5419   0    0       0        0
PR04   0        0    0       0.2052   0
```

It would be much easier to use the data with Google Visualization this way.

Basically, I want the first `GROUP BY` column as the left column, and the second `GROUP BY` column as the column headers, with the numeric value between them, like a table would normally be.

After a little work, I got a modified version of the dynamic SQL to work:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @UsePivot as VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX)

-- clever way of concatenating the rows of that column
-- just a little bit cleaner than using a cursor
-- and probably faster, too. Requires I think SQL 2008+
SELECT @UsePivot =
STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',[' + DownCode + ']'
    FROM DownCodes
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '' )

SET @sql = '
SELECT MachID, ' + @UsePivot + '  FROM
(
    SELECT MachID, DownCode, SUM(CAST(EndTime AS Float) - CAST(StartTime AS Float))/3600 AS DownTime
    FROM vReportDownLog
    GROUP BY
    MachID, DownCode
) TBL
PIVOT
(
    SUM(DownTime)
    FOR DownCode IN (' + @UsePivot + ')
)
AS Pvt'

EXEC (@sql)

ROLLBACK
```

Comment: Probably with a [`pivot`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=SQL.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PIVOT: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

```
begin transaction

declare @UsePivot as varchar(max)
declare @sql as varchar(max)
declare @downcode as varchar(100)


DECLARE rcursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT DownCode FROM DownCodes
OPEN rcursor
FETCH NEXT FROM rcursor
INTO @downcode

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

Set @UsePivot = isnull(@UsePivot,'') + '[' + LTRIM(RTRIM(@downcode)) + '],'

FETCH NEXT FROM rcursor
INTO @downcode

END 
CLOSE rcursor;
DEALLOCATE rcursor;

---Remove last comma
Set @UsePivot = SUBSTRING(@UsePivot,1,len(@UsePivot)-1)

SET @sql = '(SELECT MachID, (EndTime - StartTime)/3600 as [DownTime], ' + @UsePivot + ' as [totals] FROM vReportDownLog) as TBL '
+ 'PIVOT (SUM(DownTime) for DownCode in (' + @UsePivot + ')) as Pvt Group by MachID'


exec @sql

rollback
```

I made a dynamic query to match the downcode for all ocurrences in your table.

Comment: Couldn't that whole cursor + @usePivot expression just be replaced with a SELECT subquery? such as DownCode IN (SELECT DISTINCT DownCode FROM DownCodes) ?

Comment: @KthProg Yes, that will also work. I was trying to offer a generic solution in case you want to use pivots with specific name such as dates. If not it would be something like this: SELECT MachID, * FROM vReportDownLog PIVOT (SUM(EndTime - StartTime)/3600 for DownCode in (SELECT DISTINCT DownCode FROM DownCodes)) as Pvt Group by MachID

Comment: Is this available is 2008? SQL Server seems really uncooperative. It shows my WHERE clauses as syntax errors. I removed the WHERE clauses, and now the '-' in EndTime - StartTime is shown as a syntax error.

Comment: Can you give me the full query you are testing? I have SQL Server 2008 and tested it there so it should work. Your question does not contain any WHERE clauses.

Comment: @KthProg If you can provide table schema would be helpful as well.

Comment: Without the WHERE clauses, even this doesn't work:

SELECT MachID, * 
 FROM vReportDownLog 
 PIVOT 
 (
  SUM(EndTime - StartTime)/3600 
  FOR DownCode in (SELECT DISTINCT DownCode FROM DownCodes)
 )
 AS Pvt 
 GROUP BY MachID

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60251/discussion-between-kthprog-and-yanire-romero).

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table pivot (sum(downtime) for downcode in
(COMP,
[DIE SET],
[Die Wait],
ColorChg,
DieStart) )as pvt
```

Comment: Where would I add a 'WHERE' clause in this statement? I get syntax errors no matter where I place it.

Comment: add a one more select statement on top this query ,add where clause there.

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain more of how this works exactly, so I understand what PIVOT is doing?

Comment: we are pivoting the data based on the row values ,

Comment: Have you got the answer using this @KthProg

Comment: Unfortunately not. The full query has aliased columns, PIVOT cannot handle these. I will try to put the full query in a view, then PIVOT that view.

Comment: create a view as a same table structure and pivot the view .it will work

Comment: Yep! Thank you! I did this and then combined it with the other answers dynamic SQL. It works now.